# MVC3 Drop Down List Control does not keep State, Why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list control on a partial view and after posting the form the state of the drop down list control is not maintained

Here is the partial view cshtml code:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestCriteriaConsolidated


@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home"))
{
 <div style="float:left">
                <div style="font-weight:bold">                
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.testCriteria.Year)
                </div>
                <div style="width:110px; ">   
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.testCriteria.Year, new SelectList(new[] 
                     { 

                        new SelectListItem{ Text="All Years", Value=" " },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2010", Value="2010" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2009", Value="2009" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2008", Value="2008" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2007", Value="2007" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2006", Value="2006" }

                     }, "Value", "Text", "1"), new { @style = "width: 100px; margin-top: 5px" })          
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="float:left">
                <div>                
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="width:100px; ">                                
                     <input type="submit"  value="Results" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

}

Here is my controler code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {                     
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        string year = Request.Form["testCriteria.Year"];

        List<TestCriteriaResults> test = new List<TestCriteriaResults>();

        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "one", Value3="three", Value4="Four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3="three", Value4="four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });           

        TestCriteriaConsolidated combined = new TestCriteriaConsolidated();
        combined.testCriteriaResults = test;

        return PartialView(combined);
    }
```

NEWLY MODIFIED ACTION METHOD(This still does not maintain state):

```
public ActionResult Results()
    {
        string year = Request.Form["testCriteria.Year"];


        List<TestCriteriaResults> test = new List<TestCriteriaResults>();

        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "one", Value3="three", Value4="Four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3="three", Value4="four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });           

        TestCriteriaConsolidated combined = new TestCriteriaConsolidated();
        TestCriteria criteria = new TestCriteria() { Year = year };

        combined.testCriteriaResults = test;
        combined.testCriteria = criteria;

        return PartialView(combined);
    }
```

Comment: Couple of questions... is the form posting back to the same page? If not, what exactly is not persisting? It doesn't look like you have added the year to your view model.

Comment: I have a Criteria section that has the Years in a ddl.  I'm tyring to persist the year that was select in the ddl after returning the results from a partial view.  I hope that answerd the question?  Thanks!

Comment: The view data isn't persisted from the request to the next response. You'll need to set the Year in the new model before passing it to the view. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates the view model for your next partial view:

```
TestCriteriaConsolidated combined = new TestCriteriaConsolidated();
combined.testCriteriaResults = test;
```

You need to set the year on this model:

```
combined.testCriteria.Year = Request.Form["testCriteria.Year"];
```

Comment: And how would it be in ViewData then? Does the model binder do that automatically?

Comment: So I added logic to populate the combined.testCriteria.Year in the action method and it still does not maintain state when clicking the next page in the grid(see new code clip)

Comment: @CRice. Whooopss.... Type :) see corrected version. For some reason I was thinking TempData. :)

Comment: The Request.Form value was empty so I had to add the values to session and then pull them out of session to repopulate as you had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`combined.testCriteria.Year` needs to get set with the form value you posted

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Results(TestCriteriaConsolidated form)
    {
        List<TestCriteriaResults> test = new List<TestCriteriaResults>();
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "one", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "Four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });
        test.Add(new TestCriteriaResults { Value1 = "one", Value2 = "two", Value3 = "three", Value4 = "four" });

        TestCriteria criteria = new TestCriteria() { Year = form.testCriteria.Year };

        TestCriteriaConsolidated combined = new TestCriteriaConsolidated
                                                {
                                                    testCriteriaResults = test,
                                                    testCriteria = criteria
                                                };
        return View(combined);
    }

    public ActionResult Results() 
    { 
        return View(new TestCriteriaConsolidated());
    }
```

Comment: How would I set the value?  The reason I ask is because it would have to occur immediately after the Submit button is clicked but before the action method is hit, right?  Thanks!

Comment: combined.testCriteria.Year = year; (in action method). Otherwise use TestCriteriaConsolidated as a parameter in your action method and the model binder will take care of that for you.